# SVN Merge - Merge Changes from Trunk down to Branch not Reflected on Moved Files in Branch

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, branch, svn-trunk

I've got a folder restructuring project which is going to take an extended period of time. The restructuring will have breaking changes and cannot occur in trunk.  So the goal will be create a new Branch and keep it parallel to trunk, merging down changes down from trunk on a periodic basis.

I've attempted a few different merge methods, but i'm not able to get changes from Trunk down to the Branch on files that have moved in the Branch.

#### Trunk Structure

```
`+- /trunk
    +- /foo
        +- /bar
            - bar.php`
```

#### Branch Structure (after svn move on /bar directory)

```
`+- /branch
    +- /foo
    +- /newdir
        +- /bar
            - bar.php`
```

#### Steps

- Branched Trunk via an svn copy
- Created a new directory in Branch, /newdir
- Performed svn move on /bar directory in Branch, moving it from /foo to /newdir
- Modified bar.php in Trunk
- Tried a few different types of merges, but none will merge changes from trunk bar.php to the branch bar.php

#### Info

- Using subversion 1.8.11
- Branch does not need to be re-integrated to Trunk

#### Question

Is there any way to move files in the Branch and allow for Trunk changes to be reflected in the moved files?

Comment: Found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942000/tortoise-svn-merge-trunk-into-branch-tree-conflict